# Secure Boot is not compatible on my PC; will I be able to install Windows 8 on it?

Tags: windows-8, bios, multi-boot, secure-boot

Yesterday, I ran Windows 8 upgrade assistant on my PC, Only problem it gave is that

```
Secure Boot isn't compatible with your PC
Your PC's firmware doesn't support Secure Boot so you won't be able to use it in Windows 8.
```

My PC configuration is

```
    System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    System Model            945GCM-S2L
    System Type         X86-based PC
    Processor           Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2180  @ 2.00GHz, 2000 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
    BIOS Version/Date   Award Software International, Inc. F5u, 7/14/2008
    SMBIOS Version          2.4

    Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7600.16385"

    Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 3.00 GB
    Total Physical Memory           2.99 GB
```

Will I be able to run the windows 8 with dual boot (I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10  Installed) on this kind of configuration. Is it possible without secure boot? Or what other things people have to do who don't have secure boot? What are the problems I will face If I installed windows 8 without secure boot?

Thanks,

Ganesh

Comment: Yes you will be able to.  As for your other question a little bit of research on your part will answer those questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install windows 8 without secure boot.

You can also dual boot, though Ive not done this so I'm not sure how win8 goes about asking which drive to install on...